# Cant run artisan commands and composer Shared Hosting laravel 5.3, php version 5.4 -7.0

Tags: php, ssh, composer-php, laravel-5.3, shared-hosting

All of a sudden, my shared hosting account is causing problems; I can't run any artisan commands and keep getting syntax errors. This I understand is due to the php version I am using.

When I run the command `php -v` in ssh I get php 5.4, in my shared hosting I have selected php 7.0 in the cpanel as the version to use.

The hosting company's support team claims that ssh uses the default php version(php 5.4), if I run `composer update` or `composer install`, it goes to the next line without any output.

```
[techpgmb@server166 pw]$ php composer.phar  update
[techpgmb@server166 pw]$
```

The code works fine in localhost. I tried informing the tech support that the problem lies in the php version, but they claimed it was my code and they do not offer code debugging. Any ideas guys, I am stuck.

Comment: Something to be aware of you need to run this command in the root of your project

Comment: yes the folder pw is the root

Comment: Have you tried turning on debugging and logging for php?